# Coffeescript basic compiling error

Tags: coffeescript

Just getting started with Coffeescript and have installed it correctly , however having problems getting basic compilation to work

I have 2 folders names 'src' and 'js'

I create a simple .coffee file in the src folder called test.coffee

In the parent folder I open a terminal window and type the following

```
coffee -wc src -o js
```

This SHOULD automatically compile any .coffee files in the src folder and put in the js folder but I always get an error

```
File not found: –wc.coffee
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coffee is picky about parameter order.

> Usage: coffee [options] path/to/script.coffee -- [args]

As you see, you have to specify all options *before* the script (or directory) you want to compile:

```
coffee -w -c -o js src
```

or

```
coffee -wco js src
```

Comment: Thanks! Is Coffeescript also picky about the actual text editor you use to create the .coffee files? Now getting a different error> In src/test.coffee, Parse error on line 1: Unexpected ''

Comment: @eco_bach: Nope, not that I know of! I know my colleague has problems with hitting alt+space, which looks like a space but isn't. Might be syntax, too -- sometimes coffeescript gives a little cryptic error messages for some syntax errors. Could you post the file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the usage examples on [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/), the "watch" functionality is for files, not directories.

Try dropping the `-w`.